# can't call function inside exit()

Tags: php, function, undefined

Having a function defined in `commons.php`

```
desktop.php -> include commons.php
    |
    |
   \|/
    include MODULES.'mod.php'
```

I can call my custom function anywhere I want, but not inside an exit that's inside an if. The code where calling the function won't go:

Mod.php:

```
....
$error = mysql_error();

if($_ADM['id_user']==1) {
    if(!empty($error)) {
        $debug = array(
                    'message' => "SQL Error in infography_edit module.",
                    'line'    => '79',
                    'error'   => $error,
                    'SQL'     => $SQL
                );
        //exit(myPrint($debug)); //Calling here myPrint does not work
          exit(print_r($debug)); //This works
     }
 }

 $test = array('alex');
 exit(myPrint($debug)); //Calling here myPrint works

....

// The output error: Call to undefined function myPrint()
```

I just can't understand why anywhere else outside the code above works, but not inside it without defining it again inside

### UPDATE

Doing it this way, doesn't seem to work either:

```
myPrint($debug);
exit();
// The output error: Call to undefined function myPrint()
```

### UPDATE2

desktop.php the main file:

1. require(LIBS.'commons.php');
2. common html
3. include module

Codepad containing desktop's code: http://codepad.org/hn8QlHQ9

Comment: Can you show a working example of this on a [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) or something? There is no good reason why this shouldn't work... I suspect either a mistype or you have forgotten to include the file that defines the function before the point where you can `exit`

Comment: What error do you get? You are including commons.php before you include mod.php, right? Not sure what the arrow diagram at the top of your question means...

Comment: Check your curly braces.  You don't have any around the `if` statements.

Comment: Per update 2: You haven't included the file that contains your function definition by the time you call `exit();`!

Comment: @DaveRandom I do include commons.php before loading the module. As I mentioned, calling `myPrint` outside that if, works... inside not

Comment: @w0rldart Can you show the full code for `desktop.php`?

Comment: @w0rldart: Try adding curly braces around the `if` blocks.  I don't think the code is running the way you think it is.

Comment: @Rocket The curly braces has nothing to do with it. But tried with them on also, and nothing

Comment: @DaveRandom just edited my question and added a link to a codepad

Comment: `print_r($debug)` echos to the screen and returns nothing.  `print_r($debug, true)` returns a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all I have to clarify that the code I was working on, wasn't mine, I was just hired to make some improvements and had to talk to the main developer to explain that chaos.

What I kept missing is that every request (every single one that had to do with a page refresh) was going through a secondary file called `do.php` which eventually loaded the module that I was at, again.

Visual explication:

```
Currently at          Action                Pre-Processor        Processor 
-------------    =>   ---------------   =>  -------------    =>  ---------
add_users.php         post from form        do.php               add_user.php
```

Now, just so you know, current module location (`http://site.com/module?=add_users`) is saved in a session and `do.php` has a few lines of code to check that session and include back the module if everything ok. I know it's a huge mess, but I can't do nothing about it.

So, eventually I had to go to `do.php` and add this following line around the beginning of the file: `require_once('libs/commons.php');`

### My recommendation

Whenever you see that a function doesn't load, but you know it loads perfectly in certain cases, look for any other file that might interfere as `do.php` does above, and try including/requiring the file that contains the function.

I know things like those can give headaches, but it is what it is and most of the time is not our fault, but the way the platform was already written.

Good luck to all

Answer (score 1):

what about workaround like

```
function my_exit($msg){
   echo $msg;
   exit(1);  //Return code of the script, useful for cli scripts
}

//...
my_exit("Show message");
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work assuming that your conditional criteria is being met.

> Call to undefined function myPrint()

The above error indicates that the function `myPrint()` is not defined.  You can use the [function_exists()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) function to check if a specific function exits.  If it doesn't exist then you could redefine it in the current context.

```
<?php
if (function_exists('myPrint')) {
    echo "myPrint() exists.\n";
} else {
    echo "myPrint() doesn't exist.\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please check my update, because usually calling a function inside exit, works for me.

Comment: `exit() is not capable of executing a function` this doesn't make any sense.  It can "execute a function" just like any thing else in PHP (except `empty`), all that matters is that function's return type.

Comment: The key point here is that nested functions are executed from the inside out.

Comment: Look at my post. It does work. Take my sample and try it. Remember: PHP manual is not always up to date.

Comment: It's not the exit, it's the fact that the function won't execute inside the if for some reason

Comment: @w0rldart Try to echo a string before exit() is called so that you can test the code is running as expected. Does it output the string?

Answer (score 0):

`exit()` is a language construct capable of only accepting scalar values of type `int` and `string`. If you need to print out anything before exiting the script I suggest you do it before exit is called.

```
....
$error = mysql_error();

if($_ADM['id_user']==1)
    if(!empty($error))
        $debug = array(
                    'message' => "SQL Error in infography_edit module.",
                    'line'    => '79',
                    'error'   => $error,
                    'SQL'     => $SQL
                );
        myPrint($debug);
        exit();
....
```

Comment: I'm assuming `myPrint` returns a string.

Comment: @Rocket I think there's an awful lot of TL;DR going on here, only in this case it's just DR.

Comment: If not simply adding `echo` or `print` in front of it will do the work.

Comment: The error refers to 'undefined function'. Changing myPrint function would have no affect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using namespaces? Are you sure your function is defined? If it is included are you sure you have included it?

P.S. RobB sorry to let you know but it does work.

Example:

```
$v = 1234;
function xyz($v){
    echo $v . 23;
}
exit( xyz($v) );
```

Comment: Namespaces are not a bad shout (arguably first sensible suggestion)

Comment: Well if he has the function defined. It cannot be undefined unless he is using namespaces. As far as I know there is no other way for a function to become undefined at some point in the code, unless there's something really wrong somewhere.